# different transparency in different keyframes

Tags: transparency, keyframes

I have a text that should appear after a short time.
So I set two keyframes, try to set the transparency of the text in the first keyframe to zero and in the second on hundret percent. Blender dont differential those two keyframes - both dissapear.[image]

Comment: The transparency is not keyframed in this screenshot

Comment: I edit the transparency with the alpha property. Are there other options?

Comment: Basically, no, but the alpha property of the shader is not keyframed: it’s blue.

Comment: @blend You need to edit both the Transmission and the Alpha value.